# Filtering out bad directory paths

Tags: c#, arrays, filtering

I currently have the following code, that will count the number of directory paths that don't exist:

```
    int failedImports = 0;
    if (this.fileExplorer.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string importFile = this.fileExplorer.FileName;
        string importedDirs = File.ReadAllText(importFile);
        var result = Regex.Split(importedDirs, "\r\n|\r|\n");
        foreach (string item in result)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ToString()) && Directory.Exists(item.ToString()))
            {
                this.lstbDirectories.Items.Add(item);
            }
            else
            {
                string desc;
                failedImports++;
                if (failedImports > 1) { desc = "Directories"; } else { desc = "Directory"; } 
                lblImportStatus.Text = (String.Format("{0} {1} failed to be\nimported. Please check that\nthey exist and try again.", failedImports, desc));
            }
        }
    }
```

How would I go about writing each failed directory import into an array so I could display the failed entries to the user?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `List<string>` and call `Add()` on each bad string.

Comment: Changed my code to include lists (didn't think about that) thank you very much for your help!